# Display paragraph

Tags: asp.net

I insert the below paragraph into the database .However while displaying it is displayed as (which is not desired one):

The use of this website is subject to the following terms of use: • The content of the pages of this website is for your general information and use only. It is subject to change without notice. • Neither we nor any third parties provide any warranty or guarantee as to the accuracy,

Desired paragraph view:
The use of this website is subject to the following terms of use:

•   The content of the pages of this website is for your general information and use only. It is subject to change without notice.
•   Neither we nor any third parties provide any warranty or guarantee as to the accuracy.

How can we achieve this in asp.net/C#

Answer (score 0):

Insert the complete html into database and set into div as innerhtml

```
<div id="div" runat="server"></div>



div.InnerHtml = "paragraph from Database which saved as HTML";"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [paragraph](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) tag.

```
<p>The use of this website is subject to the following terms of use:</p>

<p>• The content of the pages of this website is for your general information and use only. It is subject to change without notice. • Neither we nor any third parties provide any warranty or guarantee as to the accuracy.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to substitute your line feed/carriage return symbols with br tags before you put the text in the control. Or, possibly put the br tag into your paragraph text when its stored in the database.

To substitute, you can use String.Replace()

The character codes can be found here http://www.asciitable.com/

Look for character codes 10 and 13.  You should check the text you're attempting to substitute, to find out if both codes are in the string, or just one of them.